# Can I mark a class abstract even if all its methods are implemented?

Tags: python, abstract-class, abc

Is there a way to mark a python class as abstract or un-instantiable even if all its abstract methods have been implemented?

```
class Component(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def operation(self) -> None:
        pass

class Decorator(Component): # I would like this class to be abstract
    def operation(self) -> None:
        print("basic operation")
```

The only workaround I found is to choose some method in the class to have both implementation and `@abstractmethod` decorator, but then python requires derivers of the child abstract class to re-implement the method.

This too can be worked around by having the child class calling `super()` , but `pylint` complains that this is a useless call.

```
class Component(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    def operation(self) -> None:
        pass

class Decorator(Component): # I would like this class to be abstract
    @abstractmethod
    def operation(self) -> None:
        print("basic operation")

class ConcreteDecorator(Decorator): 
    def operation(self) -> None: # python makes child class re-implement
        super().operation()  # pylint complains about useless super delegation
```

Is there a better way to do this?
I tried using a method with implementation and `@abstractmethod` decorator, but then deriving classes need to reimplement.
I'm looking for a solution at "compile time", not a run time error.

Comment: If all of the methods are implemented, why _is_ it considered uninstantiable? Can you provide some context on the actual problem you're trying to solve?

Comment: Sure, for example the BaseDecorator in the GOF decorator pattern. It forwards all calls as a base for Concrete Decorators that derive from it, but it would be a mistake to use it on its own. Doing this is possible in Java/C++/C#

Comment: Sounds like a `pylint` issue — can't you silence it someway?. BTW, `@abstractmethod` is a decorator, not an annotation (which is something entirely different).

Comment: I agree with this being `pylint`'s problem, not yours. But from another perspective, an abstract class is less about *preventing* instantiation than it is about ensuring that instantiation is *safe*. If you don't want `Decorator` instantiated, do what you would for any other class you don't want others to use: name it `_Decorator`, document it as a private implemantion detail, and require others to create subclasses. If `Decorator.operation` is sufficient, then leave it up to the subclasser whether they want to do more than simply call it by overriding it.

Comment: It's already trivial to bypass the abstractness of a class if you really want to instantiate it, so don't bend over backwards making a class abstract if it doesn't really need to be.

Comment: What difference is there between a `ConcreteDecorator` class with an empty body and the `Decorator` class you want to be abstract? If there doesn't need to be any new methods added or other behavior changes, why not let `Decorator` instances be created?

Comment: In this specific case an empty decorator would do nothing. Languages such as Java allow signifying that this class is not meant to be instantiated by making the class not concrete.

Comment: Python is not Java. Don't bend over backwards to forbid something with your class that does no harm and that nobody will want to do anyway.

Answer (score 1):

Create a helper class that overrides the [`__new__`](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__new__) function to check whether `cls.__bases__` contains itself.

```py
class UnInstantiable:
    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if __class__ in cls.__bases__:
            raise TypeError(f"Can't instantiate un-instantiable class {cls.__name__}")

        return super().__new__(cls)
```

Usage:

```py
# class Decorator(Component):                # Add UnInstantiable base class
class Decorator(Component, UnInstantiable):  # like this
    def operation(self) -> None:
        print("basic operation")


Decorator()  # TypeError: Can't instantiate un-instantiable class Decorator
```

Comment: I'm getting undefined variable \_\_class\_\_  on the if.    is it supposed to be if cls.__class__ ?

Comment: Which version of Python are you on?

Comment: 3.8.1 with pylance on VS code

Comment: Is that an actual runtime error or an IntelliSense error?

Comment: oh now I see it is just IntelliSense. The type error is raised successfully.